# angularjs pdf viewer - select text of pdf

Tags: angularjs, pdf

I use this directive to view pdfs:

[PDF Viewer](https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf)

and it really works fine. The only thing I would need is also to select text in PDF. Is there a possibiliy to do this or is it not doable?
Actually I am not sure if I am right but is it an image or is it the real pdf which is shown?

Comment: Its unclear, what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. If you inspect the HTML you will see the PDF is rendered in a canvas element. So it is an image that is shown rather than an actual PDF.